# Rails CSRF Token in client iPhone application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I'm planning a web app that is exposed primarily through a client application through an API. I've tried to make some requests from an iPhone client to the proof of concept application, but keep getting CSRF token errors. Is there a way of getting a token from app to then pass as a parameter in my POST request? I know I can turn off `protect from forgery`, but don't want to compromise security by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF is an attack, that works on the web only. So if you want to use your app as an API only, you can turn it off without any security flaws.

Comment: I agree with Aayush Kumar.
CSRF only works on the web, that means the attack originates from the web, the API being meant for iPhone clients does not magically protect you from it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer isn't entirely accurate.   An attacker could create a web based attack that exploits an open endpoint that was designed for ios and lacks CSRF protection.   You need to make sure that any endpoint you create is protected in some way from this sort of attack (CSRF is not the recommeneded way of securing mobile endpoints, but you certainly need to make sure that the new endpoints are not vulnerable from a web based attack).